# What determines whether NavigationCommands.BrowseBack calls the page constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationservice

I have two pages with similar logic in them. Load the page, click some buttons that will show/hide other buttons, continue to next page. When I hit the next page, if I click the back button I am returned to the previous page.

The difference is that one page (FirstPage) will have the constructor called when I click the back button, which has a call to reset the defaults. The other page (SecondPage) doesn't get the constructor called and I'm not sure why.

```
public FirstPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DisplayStuff();
}
```

FirstPage has `KeepAlive` set to `False`.

```
public SecondPage(object arg1, object arg2)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DisplayStuff(arg1, arg2);
}
```

This page also has `KeepAlive` set to `False`. These two pages don't inherit from anything and there is nothing that overrides any of the properties. The only difference I can see is the empty constructor, so I tried giving SecondPage an empty constructor and still no luck.

I'm relatively new to WPF (I work on it for an hour or two every 6 months), so what am I missing?

Here is the back button in case it is relevant.

```
<Button Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" />
```

Edit: When I click the back button, SecondPage doesn't keep its state. It just loads an empty page because `DisplayStuff` hasn't been called yet.

Navigation Code:

```
NavigateTo(new SecondPage(arg1, arg2));

protected void NavigateTo(Page page)
{
  NavigationService.Navigate(page);
}
```

Comment: Is it being cached on the client?

Comment: Could you write the navigation code between these two pages please.

Comment: @Cos, no I don't believe so. @Homam, updated with code. The navigation method is fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a similar sample application and had similar behaviour. What I figured out that when you go back to a page the constructor is not called unless the page is the first page in the journal

Read this section in [Navigation in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx):

> When the page Page is navigated back to, using the journal, the following steps take place:
>
> 1. The Page (the top journal entry on the back stack) is instantiated.
> 2. The Page is refreshed with the state that was stored with the journal entry for the Page.
> 3. The Page is navigated back to.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the information Homam. For anyone that runs into this issue, moving the logic into the Loaded event makes the second constructor call unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [Paul Stovell's article on WPF navigation](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-navigation), the way I want to display stuff is not going to work.

> When navigating, if you click "Back", WPF can't possibly know what values to pass to the constructor; therefore it must keep the page alive. Here's the trace output:

Since WPF can't call the constructor, it won't. It'll just keep the page alive.

He goes on to mention that `KeepAlive` doesn't work if you're not navigating via URI, and `Loaded` and `Unloaded` are called each time, so I can just move all my logic there and I won't need the constructor to be called on the back navigation.